# Commit behaviour of Tortoise-SVN when using a working copy based on an earlier revision

Tags: version-control, tortoisesvn

I have had massive problems with a serious of changes made to the folder structure of my working copy this morning, which have been committed to the repository. I have decided the best thing to do is to go back to yesterday evening's commit and start again.

I have deleted my working copy and checked out another one based on yesterday evening's commit.

Given that this isn't the HEAD revision, I'm not sure what happens now when I commit from the new working copy. Will SVN somehow try to incorporate the commits I made this morning (which I definitely don't want), or will it commit only the changes I've made since checking out the working copy, and create a new HEAD revision based on that?

Comment: The new commit will include ALL the revisions, including the ones I don't want. The answer is to perform a reverse merge, as described by zellus below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following command in order to remove the unwanted commit. Whereas Revision 302 might be the one you checked out again. The undo operation can be done on the repository.

```
svn merge -r HEAD:302 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/trunk
```

is described in further detail in [Undoing Changes](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch04s04.html)

Your working copy must be up to date in order to commit changes. You won't be able to commit your changes without an

```
svn update
```

I hope you don't mind the command line approach.

Comment: I found out how to do this with Tortoise anyway. This doesn't directly answer my question, but it would have solved my problem.